# Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array - What the right way to compare array value

Tags: php

I call to array and try to compare the values, is there something wrong in my syntax?

```
foreach ($xml_record_ray['inf']['rec'] as $key_item => $item) {
    $field = "100";
    if ($item["@attributes"]["tag"] == $field) {

    }
}
```

This is my array:

```
     array(1) { ["inf"]=> array(9) { ["hid"]=> string(13) "4754745675467" ["created_by"]=> string(6) "import" ["created_date"]=> string(11) "2017-01-01Z" ["last_modified_by"]=> string(13) "Update Record" ["last_modified_date"]=> string(11) "2018-01-2Z" ["originating_system"]=> string(3) "rrr" ["orid"]=> string(15) "1234565432167854" ["supp"]=> string(5) "false" ["rec"]=> array(3) { ["lead"]=> string(3) "500" ["field"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(5) "22333" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(3) "001" } } [1]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(3) "110" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(3) "001" } } } ["dfield"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["subfield"]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(2) "92" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["cod"]=> string(1) "a" } } ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["ind1"]=> string(1) " " ["ind2"]=> string(1) " " ["tag"]=> string(3) "101" } } [1]=> array(2) { ["subfield"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(4) "ntft" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["cod"]=> string(1) "b" } } [1]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(5) "nthgfr" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["cod"]=> string(1) "c" } } [2]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(5) "test2" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["cod"]=> string(1) "z" } } } ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["ind1"]=> string(1) "1" ["ind2"]=> string(1) " " ["tag"]=> string(3) "100" } } } } } } 


I compare `tag = 100` to a variable with value 100: `if ($item["@attributes"]["tag"] == $field)`
```

**This array I received after changes that used from last discussion from this post:**

```
array(1) { ["inf"]=> array(9) { ["hid"]=> string(13) "4754745675467" ["created_by"]=> string(6) "import" ["created_date"]=> string(11) "2017-01-01Z" ["last_modified_by"]=> string(13) "Update Record" ["last_modified_date"]=> string(11) "2018-01-2Z" ["originating_system"]=> string(3) "rrr" ["orid"]=> string(15) "1234565432167854" ["supp"]=> string(5) "false" ["rec"]=> array(3) { ["lead"]=> string(3) "500" ["field"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(5) "22333" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(3) "001" } } [1]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(3) "110" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(3) "001" } } } ["dfield"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["subfield"]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(2) "92" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["cod"]=> string(1) "a" } } ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["ind1"]=> string(1) " " ["ind2"]=> string(1) " " ["tag"]=> string(3) "101" } } [1]=> array(2) { ["subfield"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(4) "ntft" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["code"]=> string(1) "b" } } [1]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(5) "nthgfr" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["code"]=> string(1) "c" } } [2]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(4) "test" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["cod"]=> string(1) "z" } } } ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["ind1"]=> string(1) "1" ["ind2"]=> string(1) " " ["tag"]=> string(3) "100" } } ["subfield"]=> array(1) { [2]=> array(1) { ["@value"]=> string(12) "26A 1 2 test" } } } } } }
```

Comment: try `dd($xml_record_ray)` and show us

Comment: `string(3) "10"`?

Comment: Do You mean like this dd($xml_record_ray['inf']['rec']) as $key_item => $item ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php

Comment: This is var_dump of my array -["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["ind1"]=> string(1) "1" ["ind2"]=> string(1) " " ["tag"]=> string(3) "10" }

Comment: what is dd($xml_record_ray) do?

Comment: @newert, like @LawrenceCherone said, your dump is a bit strange : how could you have `["tag"]=> string(3) "10"` ? Is there an unicode caracter here ?

Comment: @Syscall well I hinted, so the OP might have a eureka-moment  - guess not..

Comment: Why are you setting `$field` inside the loop?

Comment: My var_dump is: $xml_record_ray = XML2Array::createArray($records->xmlsource);
       var_dump($xml_record_ray);

Comment: because the $field is my variable that I compare to the value from array

Comment: And this is the whole my var_dump array:  [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["ind1"]=> string(1) "1" ["ind2"]=> string(1) " " ["tag"]=> string(3) "100" } ["subfield"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "name" [1]=> string(5) "name2" [2]=> string(4) "test" } } } } }

Comment: I compaire tag = 100 to variable with value 100: if ($item["@attributes"]["tag"] == $field)

Comment: @Sohel0415 I tried dd($xml_record_ray) - empty

Comment: then how you expect others to help you to compare your array elements

Comment: I just asked if there is something wrong in the syntax?

Comment: If syntax is wrong, PHP interpreter will dump an warning, make sure you have enabled these.

Comment: Have no receive any errors or warnings

Comment: Do You mean appache warnings?  or in php.ini?

Comment: Thank You very much Donald Duck, I turn errors on, and receive the following error: Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in line 141 and it is:                         My if: if ($item["@attributes"]["tag"] == $field) {

Comment: So the syntax is wrong, can You help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `["@attributes"]` but `$item` is not a "standard" array. It seems to be a [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object.

Try to use the following code :

```
foreach ($xml_record_ray['inf']['rec'] as $key_item => $item) {
    $field = "100";
    if ((string)$item["tag"] == $field) {
        var_dump("Equals") ;
    }
}
```

**edit**

```
$field = "100";
foreach ($xml_record_ray['inf']['rec'] as $key_item => $item) {
    var_dump($key_item) ;
    if (is_array($item)) { 
        foreach ($item as $key_element => $element) {
            var_dump($key_element) ;
            if (!isset($element["@attributes"])) { echo("no attribute"); continue ; }
            if (!isset($element["@attributes"]['tag'])) { echo("no tag"); continue; }
            if ($element["@attributes"]["tag"] == $field) {
                var_dump("match") ;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "item is not an array" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, I receiving the following Notice: Undefined index: tag in on line 148 and line 148 is:   if ((string)$item["tag"] == $field) {

Comment: @newert Oh, ok. I didn't see you are using `XML2Array`. This works with a simpleXmlElement. Could you write your `var_dump($xml_record_ray);` please ?

Comment: I published it before: ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["ind1"]=> string(1) "1" ["ind2"]=> string(1) " " ["tag"]=> string(3) "100" }

Comment: In comments, you writes "And this is the whole my var_dump array: `[1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)`...". What is the "whole" ? Could you try my updated anwser ?

Comment: I edited This is my array: in up of the question, see please.

Comment: @newert It seems that `["rec"]` contains elements which are a list, not directly the xml element (as array). Try to add a loop around `$item`.

Comment: I changed something the first name in var_dump of my array is "inf"

Comment: what can loop can help me? I receiving XML and convert it to array, so the var_dump of the array is the array from XML

Comment: Your match is in `["rec"]["dfield"][1]["@attributes"]["tag"]`, not in `["rec"]["dfield"]["@attributes"]["tag"]`.

Comment: So what is Your advice for my case?

Comment: I checked Your answer "edit" and receiving: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - foreach ($item as $element) {

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: subfield in  line 158: ("foreach ($item['subfield'] as $key_subfield => $subfield") { ) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in  on line 158 - subfield is critery by wich I am find the looking for my way to change the information in array. "ntft"

Comment: So, the last thing I could say : add more tests (`isset()`), add more traces (`echo` or `var_dump()`). I've edited my anwser. Good luck.

Comment: I changed the  foreach ($item['subfield'] as $key_subfield => $subfield) {  to:  foreach ($element['subfield'] as $key_subfield => $subfield) { And receiving the following Error: string(1) "z" Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '[Array2XML] Illegal character in tag name. tag: 2 in node: dfield' in Stack trace: #0 Array2XML::convert('dfield', Array) #1 Array2XML::convert('rec', Array) Array2XML::convert('inf', Array) #3  Array2XML::convert('scrubbed', Array) #4 Array2XML::createXML('scrubbed', Array) #5 {main}

Comment: I think it is mean I going on, but the different type of the arrays give the error in convert array to XML?

Comment: Have You any mind about it? And thank You for help me.

Comment: Syscall please see the attached array(chenges in the top of the topic), I added after I did all You told.

Comment: Syscall can You answer me please?

Comment: @newert I don't know why you are trying to convert XML to an Array, but I think it is really easier to use SimpleXMLElement (and use my first anwser) like it seems to be at the origin. Also, it's not easy to us to test your script/array because we can't copy/paste your data to test it (maybe send a `var_export($data, true)`, or a JSON). I will be glade to help you, but I can't spent many time to this anwser.

Comment: Thank You for Your reply Syscall, I convert XML to array because I should do search by criteria and change it if need. And I don't know how can I do it in XML not converted to array.

Comment: I tried all You tel me, but there is one problem, in SimpleXMLElement there no attribute "tag" else just:  
                                                                   
 object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["ind1"]=> string(1) "1" ["ind2"]=> string(1) " " ["tag"]=> string(3) "100" } ["subfield"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "text" [1]=> string(5) "text2" [2]=> string(4) "test" } } } } }  So I can't find the need attribute.

Comment: And in the array yes:                                                                                                 
array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(5) "text1" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["code"]=> string(1) "c" } } [2]=> array(2) { ["@value"]=> string(4) "test" ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["code"]=> string(1) "z" } } } ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { ["ind1"]=> string(1) "1" ["ind2"]=> string(1) " " ["tag"]=> string(3) "100" }